# Hibernate fetching issue in table which has no primary key

Tags: java, sql, hibernate

I have one mapping table that has no primary key. It has just 2 columns like  student_id and test_id
each student has multiple tests

```
student_id  test_id
1001        21
1001        52
1001        35
1001        29
1001        12
```

when i wrote query

```
select test_id from test_map where student_id =1001
```

It fetch the correct records but when i feched through hibernate criteria  it shows 5 values with test_id as 21 only

in my pojo
 i tried with student_id as @ID,and no @ID in that pojo

```
Criteria criteria = session.createCriteria(StudentTestMapping.class);
        criteria.add(Restrictions.eq("studentId", studentId));

        List<StudentTestMapping> screenList=criteria.list();
        Iterator<StudentTestMapping> testItr = screenList.iterator();
        while (testItr.hasNext()) {
            StudentTestMapping studentTestMap = (StudentTestMapping) testItr.next();
            Long testId = studentTestMap.getTestId();
            System.out.println("testId : " + testId);
        }



StudentTestMapping.java

    @Entity
    @Table(name = "test_map")
    class StudentTestMapping{

     Long studentId;
     Long testId;


    @ID
    @Column(name = "student_id")
    public Integer getStudentId()
    {
        return this.studentId;
    }

    public void setStudentId(Integer studentId)
    {
        this.studentId = studentId;
    }

    @Column(name = "test_id")
    public String getTestId()
    {
        return this.testId;
    }

    public void setTestId(String testId)
    {
        this.testId = testId;
    }

    }
```

Comment: Can u provide some more informations here  like your criteria code and mappings

Comment: An ID is supposed to uniquely identify a row in the table. Without the code of your entity, the code you're executing, example input and example output, we can't help much.

Comment: I have updated with code

Comment: Your mapping doesn't make sense: studentId doesn't uniquely identify a row of your table. You need to add a real ID column, or to use a composite ID.

Answer (score 0):

1) Make sure your pojo implements Serializable.

2) You can annotate the studentId as a NaturalId.

```
@NaturalId
@Column(name = "student_id")
public Integer getStudentId()
{
    return this.studentId;
}
```

And you can access it by:

```
session.bySimpleNaturalId(StudentTestMapping.class)
   .load(studentId)
```

3) Your entity must have an id. You can add an auto incrementing identity column or as mentioned you can create a composite key with all the columns.
[Basic O/R Mapping](http://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/core/3.5/reference/en/html/mapping.html#mapping-declaration-id)